# Is there way to specify document aware token filter in SOlr?

Tags: solr, tokenize

I want to write TokenFilter which behaves differently depending on other InputSolrDocument fields.
 I've tried to accomplish this via ThreadLocal and InputProcessor but they run in different threads...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot do that, see for instance the discussion [here.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1536) You could try using an UpdateProcessor